# Redirect on bad subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a before_filter in the application controller called find_subdomain

```
  def find_subdomain
    if !request.subdomain.empty?
      client = Client.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
      redirect_to root_url(subdomain: false) if client.nil?
    end
  end
```

However, when I try to navigate to an incorrect subdomain the before filter does not execute, and I just get the "Oops! Google Chrome could not find ...." page. Any ideas?

Comment: develop or production?

Comment: On the chrome page can you click "More" or use ie/firefox. It should give more info and what URL do you end up at?

Comment: The incorrect subdomain I tried navigating to still shows in the address bar. In firefox I get a similiar page, "Firefox can't find the server at foo.mywebsite.com". However, if I try this on staging (this code isn't deployed there yet) I get one of those "We're sorry, but something went wrong." pages.

Comment: this is a concern for your webserver (nginx, apache) and especially your nameserver.